# How to handle an HTML Response From Angular

Tags: node.js, angular, httpclient

NodeJs (server) can handle a request and send an HTML response(file) like this:

```
res.status(404).sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'views', 'error404.html'));
```

if we want to get some json data from server, it would be handled like this in angular:

```
  getPosts() {
    this.http.get<any>('http://localhost:3000/api/posts')
      .subscribe((postData) => {
        this.posts = postData.posts;
        this.postsUpdated.next([...this.posts]);
    });
```

now, if an HTML file is requested by angular, how can it handle and display the contents of the file in the respective comp.component.html file in angular.

I hope you understand my question, thanks in advance.

Comment: Is `[innerHTML]` what you're looking for? https://alligator.io/angular/innerhtml-binding-angular/

Comment: Thanks for the reply, innerHTML can help for displaying HTML content from .ts file to .html file, so it helped but not completely because i cannot convert an HTML file to string.